# Can we ensemble fastText along with SVM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to ensemble the three different models (FastText, SVM, NaiveBayes).

I thought of using python to do this. I'm sure that we can ensemble NaiveBayes as well as SVM models. But, can we ensemble fastText using python ?

Can anyone please suggest me regarding the same ...

Comment: What does "ensemble" mean to you?

Comment: @coldspeed if I understand correctly OP wants to combine the output of these model to create a new model(stacking).

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar  yes.. I'm planning to combine the output of these models to create a new model

Answer (score 0):

The approach you can apply for *combining*  multiple models is not related with the way you are going to implement it in Python/Java/R.

Maybe what you are looking for is [Ensemble learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning).

One of the most popular approach to achieve an ensemble of different models is *stacking*, which involves learning a new model on how to combine the predictions of individual models you have already trained. See [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implementing-stacking-scratch-python/) tutorial which uses Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Coming to my question, can we use fast text algorithm in ensemble learning ?

Answer (score 0):

In your use case *you can* as you're dealing with 3 models you should keep in mind that:

- The models have different mechanics to use the `predict()` method:

  - `FastText` uses an internal file (serialized model with `.bin` extension, for example) with all embeddings and `wordNGrams` and you can pass raw text directly;
  - `SVM` and `NaiveBayes` you're obligated to pre-process the data using `CountVectorizer`, `TfidfVectorizer` `LabelEncoder`, get the result, repass for the `LabelEncoder` and deliver the result.
  - You will need at the end deal with different probabilities (if you're predicting with `k > 1`) and probably you need to take care of this
- If you're going to serialize it to production you'll need to pickle the `SVM` and `NB` models and use `.bin` for `FastText model` and of course the embeddings from the former ones need to be instantiated too. This can be a little pain in your response time if you need to predict in near real time.